# SIGABRT in NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods after mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: ios, core-data

**The good facts:**

- I download data from the server, and, via Core Data thread confinement, save the data, and when the background MOC is saved, the main MOC gets merged.
- All the saving operations go ok
- Also the merging of the MOC happens without any problems

**The bug I'm hunting:**

- When my UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController is active (i.e. on the screen), and the saving is happening, the app crashes with a SIGABRT that takes me to the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification line in AppDelegate.
- What is the most strange part is, that when the delegate of the FRC is nil, or when it is my view controller but i don't implement any FRC delegate methods, the crash doesn't happen and I don't have any problem. But when I implement any of the delegate methods (even empty, without a single line of code), the app crashes with the same bug. **It means that the methods are not even being fired, the problem is not in the code inside these methods**.
- The strangest part 2 **(CHECK UPDATE 2 BELOW)**: the crash happens with a `[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` and I don't call any 'length' property in my CoreDataManager neither in my AppDelegate class

**The witness: console**

```
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<AppDelegate.m:(352)> Will merge
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<AppDelegate.m:(355)> Did merge
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<AppDelegate.m:(352)> Will merge
<AppDelegate.m:(355)> Did merge
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<MyTableViewController.m:(134)> Fetched results controller did fetch 
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
<AppDelegate.m:(352)> Will merge
<CoreDataManager.m:(338)> Saved data from server
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13318050
```

**Some code - Merging the MOCs**

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *sender = (NSManagedObjectContext *)[notification object];

    if ((sender != self.managedObjectContext) &&
        (sender.persistentStoreCoordinator == self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator))
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            DebugLog(@"Will merge");
            [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
            DebugLog(@"Did merge");
        });
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

Following Cocoanetics hint, I created a NSNumber category to check who is calling `length`. I got what you see below, and a crash in **[__NSCFNumber _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

[image]

**Update 2**
Enabling zombies didn't help =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after months and hours, I finally got a solution. It works, and I would love to hear some opinions on why.

So, as I said, the saving was working 100%, as well as the merging notifications. If I set the NSFetchedResultsController delegate to nil, there was no problem. However, setting the delegate to my UIViewController, made the app crash.

I thought it could be, maybe due to my code when the delegate methods were triggered. But the app crashed even before that. So I followed Cocoanetics tip, to create a category and try to figure out who was calling the `length` method to the NSNumber object. After that, I saw that the NSPredicate was calling `- (BOOL)evaluateWithObject:(id)object;` before getting to the crash. In the same way, I did a category to override it:

```
@interface NSPredicate (PractiPredicate)
- (BOOL)evaluateWithObject:(id)object;
@end

@implementation NSPredicate (PractiPredicate)

- (BOOL)evaluateWithObject:(id)object
{
    NSLog(@"Evaluate was called. Object class %@", NSStringFromClass([object class]));
    MyManagedObject *myManagedObject = object;
    NSLog(@"Is fault? %d", myManagedObject.isFault);
    NSLog(@"myManagedObject changed and already have propertyA? %d", myManagedObject.propertyA != nil);
    return YES;
}

@end
```

So, for my surprise, it worked, and generated te following logs:

> Evaluate was called. Object class MyManagedObject
>
> Is fault? 0
>
> myManagedObject changed and already have propertyA? 1

I decided to print "Is fault?" because I thought that this mess was related to NSManagedObject faulting, but, for what it printed, it's not.

Question for the comments: What do you think that could have generated this problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are only observing the notification from other MOCs. If you save there this triggers another such notification and you might be going in an endless loop that fails after one or two iterations because an object had been released by ARC.

Comment: Is it always [NSNumber length]? Try creating a category on NSNumber and implement an empty length method. Then put a break point in there and check the stack trace where this is being called.

Comment: Edited, I'm pretty sure that Mugunth is right, just don't know how to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yours sounds like a memory issue. Check your ARC ownership qualifiers and enable NSZombies. Enabling NSZombies will help you narrow down the object that was released prematurely.

When you enable zombies you will see a "message sent to a deallocated instance" instead. Check which object was released prematurely and update your question.

Comment: Hi Mugunth. I enabled NSZombies, but it didn't help. I keep getting the SIGABRT (Not EXC_BAD_ACCESS)...

Comment: By enabling Zombies, you will still crash, but at least the error will be meaningful instead of some garbage pointer pointing to a NSNumber, trying to call length. Can you post that response?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem does not lie in the code you posted but in how you deal with the changes in the fetched results controller delegate. Those are just being triggered by the merge.

Comment: As I say in the question, even if I only NSLog in only one of the delegate methods and don't implement others, it crashes. The triggering is the problem, not the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case, i found out that the reason for the crash was an incorrect predicate. I had a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute > 0"];
```

Where attribute was a string. I corrected it as:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute.length > 0"];
```

Now, my code is running fine. Make sure you check all the predicates in your code since this can also be a reason for this crash.